# How to mass 'reassign' all foreign keys for a user in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In this scenario, a user has multiple Foreign Key relationships across multiple 'apps' within the Django project. This user decides to leave the platform so wants to easily transfer all Foreign Key relationships to another user.

Would it be possible to get a list of all objects that the user has a Foreign Key relationship to and mass reassign them? Or is there a simpler way?

Thanks

```
# models.py

class Post(models.Model):
     ...
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASSCADE)
     ...

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
     ...
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASSCADE)
     ...

class YetAnotherModel(models.Model):
     ...
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASSCADE)
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it within your User model:

```
old_user.post_set.all().update(created_by=new_user)

old_user.anothermodel_set.all().update(created_by=new_user)

old_user.yetanothermodel_set.all().update(created_by=new_user)
```

Or you can do it within the models itself:

```
Post.objects.filter(created_by=old_user).update(created_by=new_user)
AnotherModel.objects.filter(created_by=old_user).update(created_by=new_user)
YetAnotherModel.objects.filter(created_by=old_user).update(created_by=new_user)
```

if you have a lot of different models you can do it like

```
models = (Post, AnotherModel, YetAnotherModel)
for model in models:
    model.objects.filter(created_by=old_user).update(created_by=new_user)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already thought of this approach but I would like to make it dynamic so when future models are added the same method would work. You know how the Django admin will warn you what relationships would 'break' on deleting a model with a foreign key relationship, is there a way to 'piggyback' off that?

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a list of relations from/to the `User` model, and then perform an update:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

my_user = User.object.get(username='my_username')
new_user = User.objects.get(username='new_username')

for f in my_user._meta.get_fields():
    if f.is_relation and f.one_to_many:
        name = f.remote_field
        getattr(my_user, f.att_name).all().update(**{remote_field: new_user})
```

We here thus will make queries per relation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like:

```
old_user = User.objects.get(username='old_username')
new_user = User.objects.get(username='new_username')

for related in old_user._meta.related_objects:
    related.related_model.objects.filter(created_by=old_user).update(created_by=new_user)
```

`_meta.related_objects` is django 1.8+ I think

Pretty sure it'd work with this too:
`for related in User._meta.related_objects: ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can make it automatically both to work in a request or also in a Command.

First change the on_delete to SET_NULL this will made it able to add some logic, so it doesn't delete the related record immediately

```
# models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class AnotherModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class YetAnotherModel(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

To make it automatically you have two options, both using signals:

Option 1: More specific to the delete user logic, you can soon as the user is deleted remove all related ownership and give it to another user.

This will be trigger once, and can be very efficient in a large database.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def default_created_by_to_user(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs["instance"]

    default_user = User.objects.get(username='default')

    # * Here you will have to register all the related models to change the owner
    # * Filter all the owned records from the user and perform the update on them with the new default user
    Post.objects.filter(created_by=instance).update(created_by=default_user)
    AnotherModel.objects.filter(created_by=instance).update(created_by=default_user)
    YetAnotherModel.objects.filter(created_by=instance).update(created_by=default_user)
```

Option 2: Updating from target models. This is more robust as it will be trigger when the user is deleted and also when the created_by is set to None. Just register the same receiver function for all the models with the `created_by` field.

This will be triggered for every Record, it can be slow in large database, but you can also move it to a background job using celery.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post)
@receiver(post_save, sender=AnotherModel)
@receiver(post_save, sender=YetAnotherModel)
def default_created_by_to_user(sender, **kwarg):
    instance = kwargs["instance"]

    # created_by will be None when the user is deleted
    if instance.created_by:
        default_user = User.objects.get(username='default')

        # * sender is the model class.
        # * Updating with update() will avoid to trigger post_save again
        sender.objects.filter(pk=instance.pk).update(created_by=default_user)
```